# How to Plot CDF and PDF in R for a new function

Tags: r

How can I plot CDF and PDF in R for

```
 f <- function(x) {((2*a*b)/(x^3))*((exp(-b/(x^2))^a))}
```

with range 0 to infinity

Comment: so x is [,+inf), and you want the CDF and PDF of f(x). What's a and b

Comment: `?curve` will do that for the pdf (or curves in general)

Comment: a and b are parameters of exponentiated inverse rayleigh distribution and curves of pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use something like this (because I like ggplot2):

```
a <-1
b <- 2
f <- function(x) {((2*a*b)/(x^3))*((exp(-b/(x^2))^a))}

x <- seq(1, 20)
pdf <- f(x)
cdf <- cumsum(pdf)

library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x, pdf, cdf)
ggplot(df, aes(x, pdf))+geom_line()
ggplot(df, aes(x, cdf))+geom_line()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should specify `a` and `b` as arguments to the function, with default values. Then `curve` can be used to plot the function.

```
f <- function(x,a=0.5,b=4.5) {((2*a*b)/(x^3))*((exp(-b/(x^2))^a))}        
curve(f)
```

The way your code is now, `a` and `b` are most likely resolving to whatever is in the global environment, which you may not want later and could cause problems reproducing your results.

Comment: I have specified a and b and f is a PDF.