# Plotting a PDF of a custom function that does not integrate to 1 using R

Tags: r, function, plot

I want to plot the PDF for a custom function (as opposed to predefined ones such as normal or the gamma distributions, suggested as an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55172883/12629562) to a similar question) for example `fX(x) = 1 - x` for `-1 <= x <= 1`. By definition the PDF should integrate to 1.

```
f <- function(x) 1 - x

integrate(f, lower = -1, upper = 1)$value

[1] 2
```

Therefore using for example `curve(f, -1, 1)` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28728500/12629562) only plots the function and not the PDF as it does not integrate to 1.

One can do the mathematical transformation and obtain the function to be plotted but is there an package that could do that automatically?

Comment: What do you mean "PDF for a custom function"? PDF is defined for a random variable, not function. Do you have a CDF and want to plot its corresponding PDF?

Comment: @slava-kohut there must be something that I'm confusing so I need to give the long story here. I have a random variable X with a PDF fX(x)=1-|x| for -1 <= x <= 1 (here it does integrate to 1). And I have a function Y=2X with unknown PDF, Is there a function in R that can calculate the PDF of Y?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to be able to take a function with specific upper and lower bounds, then normalize it so that its definite integral equals one. Here's how you can do that:

```r
pseudo_pdf <- function(func, lower = -1, upper = 1)
{
  m <- integrate(func, lower = lower, upper = upper)$value
  func2 <- function(x) func(x)/m
  curve(func2, lower, upper, ylab = "Density")
  invisible(func2)
}

f <- function(x) 1 - x

pseudo_pdf(f, lower = -2, upper = 1)
```

[image]

Or suppose we want to transform a function so that it returns a "pdf-generating" function:

```r
f2 <- function(x) x^2 + 3
f3 <- pseudo_pdf(f2, 1, 3)
```

[image]

So we can see that even though our original function does not integrate to 1 in the interval, our new function does:

```r
integrate(f2, lower = 1, upper = 3)
#> 14.66667 with absolute error < 1.6e-13
integrate(f3, lower = 1, upper = 3)
#> 1 with absolute error < 1.1e-14
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>